# Installing floating floor and keep getting gaps

Tags: flooring, laminate-floor, pergola

My sister and I are installing pergo max premier which is a new verison of their floating floor, my sister has installed 2 laminate floors before and this type is a lot thicker with less give and more difficult to work with.

Each peace we really have to pound in place with a hammer and a tapping block, we are running it along a very big room, close to 150 feet in length and we are noticing that once we get to the 4th row the very first row against the floor a few gaps between the pieces are forming.

We have disconnected and redid the floors twice but it seems from us using the hammer and tapping block it's causing gaps in the rows that we have already done and the pieces don't seem to be locking in place like the should even though when we set them they are set as in as much as they can go.

Does anyone have any experience with this happening and how to fix it as we don't want to continue adding new rows when the first few rows gaps keep appearing.

Comment: Do you think that using [installation straps](http://www.jharris.net/Rockshire/Renovation%20Pictures/pergo%20install%201.JPG) would be helpful? I think they were originally made for the glue-together floors, but it could help with whatever is jostling your planks apart.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't worked with the newer Pergo; the last I installed was in 2007.

However, check the installation basics (from [here](https://na.pergo.com/pdfs/installation/max_securelock_install.pdf) and [here](https://na.pergo.com/pdfs/installation/Installation_Essentials_Guide.pdf)):

- Are you installing in the correct direction?  The tongue facing upward should be on the floor and the next piece goes on top of it.
- Is the floor flat?
- Is the flooring material acclimated to between 65 °F and 72 °F for at least 48 hours?
- Are you alternating seams so they are at least 12 inches offset from each row?
- Are you *not* tapping from the sides?
- Are you providing 1/2 inch clearance from the walls, pipes, and other fixed objects?  (3/8 is for rooms smaller than 40 feet.)
- Are you damaging the tongues or seams?
- Are you using T molding across the width of the room?  See the instructions for rooms longer than 40 feet.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing that anyone on the internets can help you with.  You have to do more due diligence to each board.  If ONE board isn't tapped in correctly it will throw off everything.  In a room as big as yours that is a huge mess.   I have worked with your exact flooring and all that I can say is completely scrutinize every board.

Also you should not be installing these in rows - hence your problem.  You should install 4-5 rows at a time and work yourself in sections of 10-15 feet.  Then you can see any tapping issues that you have.

A room that big is a TOUGH install.  Missing one out of 50 planks is TOUGH.  Follow my advice with doing more than a row at a time.  The good news is that you are just a little off.  Which means you are probably just missing putting one plank into place - since that will throw everything there after off.  If you had multiple issues in one area you would be way off.